# pygame `.mid` audio files sounds different on other platforms

Tags: python, windows, macos, audio, pygame

I was creating a RPG style game on my Mac machine running windows, I used some `.mid` files I found in another game for the music, so after about a week of coding and testing this game over and over, getting use to the music, I reinstall Mac OS X, and pygame for mac, and when I start up the the exact same game with the exact same sound files (after being compressed via `rar` format (which has never had an effect on anything windows)), I notice the music sounds quite different the notes and sounds sound more clear, and the tunes in the music tend to carry on longer, It sounds a lot nicer, But I have absolutely no idea why this happens. Anyone know?

I also noticed that there is no default software mac comes with that will play a `mid` file.
So I can't rely hear what it sounds like on mac anyway. Perhaps its pygame? perhaps its just os

Comment: That's probably just the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because MIDI is a sound protocol format, not an encoded sound file.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI

Specifically,

> MIDI carries event messages that specify notation, pitch and velocity, control signals...

That means the MIDI interpretation is OS, or music player, dependent, so the sound may be different.

In your case, the OS holds samples of instruments and the sound sounds differently because of the different samples.

Comment: I had a feeling that may be what it was. I should have researched that. But like I couldn't even play the sound file unless through pygame. Thanks :)